# Microsoft flow cant't connect to Office 365

Tags: office365connectors

I am trying to link flow with office 365 outlook, every time I try and authorise the connection I get;

```
OAuth2Certificate authorization flow failed for service 'Office 365 
(Discovery, Certificate)'. O365 discovery endpoint returned status code 401 
(Unauthorized). Response:\r\n{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":"Access denied. You do not have 
permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}
```

I am the owner of the office 365 and this is a home account not a business one, I am not sure if this makes a difference.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 4):

I've also faced the same issue and now it's working fine after switching to "Outlook.com". 
The below is from the official documentation: 
    
 > For Azure work or school accounts, select Office 365 Outlook.
    
 > For personal Microsoft accounts, select Outlook.com.

So, I think one need to use "Outlook.com" for the home account.